Add timecode per frame using ffmpeg
I am trying to find a way to add timecodes to each frame of my outgoing streams, so I can synchronize them in my (live) streaming backend. It does not matter if it was SEI, or VITC or LTS timecodes, whataver works would be fine.
I have tried this line:
ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i CYMTV_Front_Page.mp4 -timecode 18:09:00:00 -vf scale="720:480" -c:v libx264 -f mpegts generated-output.ts
But then when I use ffprobe to look at the frames, the [SIDE_DATA] is not there - only in the first frame.
Any help would be appreciated..
Thanks,
Ron
